# Postgresql get position of first not null in array

Tags: postgresql

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36420960/1117305) question I got the idea of using `array_position`

```
CREATE Temp TABLE foo (
    id    integer PRIMARY KEY,
      name  text[] NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO foo (id, name) VALUES
    (1, array[NULL,'c7b74ea7a0ee2924ca6f2fb4f90ac378',NULL]);
INSERT INTO foo (id, name) VALUES 
    (2, array[NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'4bf4b5c141a361e4eac28b405b31baeb',NULL,'4bf4b5c141a361e4eac28b405b31baeb',NULL]); 

select array_position(d.name,(array_agg( x.v) FILTER (WHERE x.v IS NOT NULL))[1])
from foo d
  cross join lateral unnest(d.name) as x(v)
group by d.name;
```

returns the correct answer:

```
| "array_position"|
|:---------------:|
|      2          |
|      6          |
```

Is there a better function to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id, array_position(name, (array_remove(name, NULL))[1])
FROM foo;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/WBUAD_vU